# Django: AttributeError: 'Q' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, django

I try to get the count of all attendees. I created the following `for loop` and `query set`. However, I always get the error `AttributeError: 'Q' object has no attribute 'count'`. Do you have an idea how to fix that?

```
# Get count of attendees per ticket and then combine these
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(event=3)
count = 0
for ticket in tickets:
    new_count = ticket.attendees.filter=Q(
        canceled=False,
        order__status__in=(
            OrderStatus.PAID,
            OrderStatus.PENDING,
            OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_REFUNDED,
            OrderStatus.FREE,
        ),
    ).count()
    count += new_count
print(count)
```

Comment: The correct syntax would be:`....attendees.filter(Q(...)).count()`. No additional `=` in there. That way `count()` is called on the `Queryset`, not the `Q` object-

Comment: Thank you! Additionally, it seems like the `Q` wasn't necessary at all.

Comment: @JoeyCoder: no, usually a `Q` is only necessary when you want to write logical ORs, or when you want to pass filters as objects (so as a parameter, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned to `.filter`: note that you wrote `.filter=Q(`, not `.filter(Q(...))`.

You can fix this with:

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(event=3)
count = 0
for ticket in tickets:
    new_count = ticket.attendees.filter(
        canceled=False,
        order__status__in=(
            OrderStatus.PAID,
            OrderStatus.PENDING,
            OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_REFUNDED,
            OrderStatus.FREE,
        )
    ).count()
    count += new_count
print(count)
```

That being said, I think your handle this more effectively with a single call that looks like:

```
Attendee.objects.filter(
    ticket__event=3,
    canceled=False,
    order__status__in=(
        OrderStatus.PAID,
        OrderStatus.PENDING,
        OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_REFUNDED,
        OrderStatus.FREE,
    )
).count()
```

So here we count the number of `Attendee`s with a `ticket` for `event=3`. This will likely be more efficient than making *n* queries.